# SyncAdapter & SyncResult

Tags: android, synchronization

I want to know what is the default behavior of `SyncManager` when we use the object `SyncResult` during the operation `onPerformSync()`

For instance, when sync is in error due to `IOException`, we set

```
syncResult.stats.numIoExceptions++
```

Then `SyncManager` must manage the re-send sync until a delay specify by the system.

But how many times the sync is re-call if `IOException` accurs at each sync?
What is the default delay set between each sync?
Is that possible to define its own behaviors?
Where can I find documentation about that?

Answer (score 7):

The `SyncResult` object has a `delayUntil` field that you can set from your sync adapter which will delay each following sync by the specified number of seconds. Maybe this is the field you're looking for.

Otherwise, the sync will be rescheduled if

`SyncResult.madeSomeProgress()` returns true - i.e. some work was successfully accomplished by the sync (corresponding to `stats.numDeletes`, `stats.numInserts > 0`, `stats.numUpdates > 0`)

`SyncResult.hasSoftError()` returns true - i.e. it failed due to an `IOException` or because `SyncResult.syncAlreadyInProgress` was true.

So to answer your question, if `IOException`s occur at EVERY sync, the `SyncManager` will retry ad infinitum - with exponential backoff.

The caveat to this is that the sync adapter can set `SyncResult.tooManyRetries = true` which will indicate to the `SyncManager` that the sync is not to rescheduled.

Comment: I have an encryption enabled... if there are no keys i want syncadpater to trigger sync later. There is no definite time for sync delay. How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

The initial retry time:

```
/**
 * When retrying a sync for the first time use this delay. After that
 * the retry time will double until it reached MAX_SYNC_RETRY_TIME.
 * In milliseconds.
 */
private static final long INITIAL_SYNC_RETRY_TIME_IN_MS = 30 * 1000; // 30 seconds
```

You can tell the framework to stop retrying the sync by setting `SyncResult#tooManyRetries` to `true`.

Source: [SyncManager.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/content/SyncManager.java)